# scale problems with gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The model that I import as stl from SolidWorks is scaled in mm. When I visualize the model in gazebo it´s awfully huge. So I use Meshlab to rescale it.

However, upon launching gazebo dies instantly with the following error:

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 5687, exit code -6].
log files: /home/fxm-lc/.ros/log/48312cc6-6942-11e1-84ee-c8600006c2de/gazebo-2*.log

Any suggestion are welcome, thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29364/scale-problems-with-gazebo/) by [Lucian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1876/lucian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While opening and re-saving is a feasible approach most of the time, it can occasionally lead to problems, like properties getting lost in the process (or even crashes, sometimes). Have you tried the scale tag as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/visual)? If you're talking about gazebo .world files, these also support scaling the mesh.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3